# Repeat gradient in a div

Tags: css, radial-gradients

Hei i have this code in CSS:

```css
.gradient-four {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle closest-side, red, purple);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-four"></div>
```

And it´s applied to a div. How can i repeat that div, without repeating the code over and over? I tried the background repeat but that would´t do the trick.Is it possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To repeat a linear/radial-background you simply need de specify a size then you may adjust the background-repeat to choose how to repeat it:

```css
.gradient-four {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle closest-side, red, purple);
  background-size:50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-four"></div>

<div class="gradient-four" style="background-repeat:repeat-x"></div>
<div class="gradient-four" style="background-repeat:repeat-y"></div>
```

And if you want to repeat the result of the whole div you have, you may adjust the gradient like this:

```css
.gradient-four {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  float: left;
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle closest-side, red, purple 98%, transparent 100%);
  background-size:100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-four"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`repeating-radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-radial-gradient) function. It takes the same parameters as `radial-gradient` and functions the same, just repeating.

Answer (score 0):

Use `repeating-radial-gradient` like so:

```
.gradient-four {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  float: left;
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, red, purple 49px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, red, purple 49px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, red, purple 49px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(center center, red, purple 49px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coxzocnn/13/)

Comment: in your case you don't even need repeating-radial-gradeint : https://jsfiddle.net/coxzocnn/16/